# JBehave + TestNG + Selenium Grid - generate jbehave index.html report file for each seperate selenium node when using single jbehave story file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, bdd, selenium-grid, jbehave

I have a JBehave project in which need to integrate with TestNG and Selenium grid which using [this](https://github.com/ULei/jbehave-testng-example/blob/master/src/test/java/testng/CoreStoriesUsingTestNG.java), [this](https://github.com/garyfoxes/UsingMavenWithTestNG/blob/28b292c56116ffa0b1daebce3022ec9627ce70d9/src/main/java/testngexamples/seleniumgrid/TestSuiteBase.java) and [this](https://github.com/michelleXIE2014/testNG-jbehave-test-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lazycode/TraderEmbedderTest.java) code in github *(sorry since i cant past the entire code so only showing the reference)* i have done the JBehave + TestNG + Selenium Grid.

But my problem is when using **single Story** file to execute in different Selenium node the jbehave report `index.html` file is shown for any one node only. I want to have separate report for each node in a single or more jbehave report index.html file. I should not run with two story files and all, how can i show separate report for each and every Selenium node in a single jbehave report html file.

I know the jbehave use [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) for their report generation but i have no clue on how to override this and show report for each selenium nodes. Any idea please share.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tried a way and found it to be an temporary solution for it now.

1. Create a String variable that gets the details in Story Runner Class.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = (RemoteWebDriver) DriverManager.getDriver();
        String hostname = hng.getHostName(driver.getSessionId());
        String browserName = driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName();
        String browserVersion = driver.getCapabilities().getVersion();
```

2. Then pass that value to the Story Embedded class as shown below.

```
Embedder storyEmbedder = new StoryEmbedder(driver, browserName + "v" + browserVersion);
```

3. In the Story Embedded class assign that String value as shown below

```
private WebDriver driver;
    private static String name;
    public StoryEmbedder(WebDriver driver, String hostname) {
            this.driver = driver;
            this.name = hostname;
        }
```

4. Then in the Configuration method inside the useStoryReporterBuilder function add the following code.

```
.withRelativeDirectory(name) //where 'name' is the String variable refer above step.
```

5. like the return will be as follows

```
return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                    .useStoryControls(new StoryControls().doDryRun(false).doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false))
                    .useStoryLoader(
                            new LoadFromClasspath(embedderClass))
                    .useStoryParser(
                            new RegexStoryParser(
                                    examplesTableFactory))
                    .useStoryPathResolver(new UnderscoredCamelCaseResolver())
                    .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                            new StoryReporterBuilder().withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(embedderClass))
                                    .withDefaultFormats().withPathResolver(new ResolveToPackagedName())
                                    .withViewResources(viewResources).withReporters(new MyStoryReporter())
                                    .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.XML).withFailureTrace(true)
                                    .withFailureTraceCompression(true).withCrossReference(xref).withRelativeDirectory(name)).useParameterConverters(parameterConverters)
                    // use '%' instead of '$' to identify parameters
                    .useStepPatternParser(new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser("%"));
```

Now i can have two folders based on browser and browser version.

If you guys have any better answer please do help by posting it. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think combining Jbehave and TestNG is a better idea. Jbehave supports the stories and using testng, there would be of no use, like grouping, parameter,etc. There are existing JunitStories class which works fine with Jbehave. If your using it for organizing your test results, you can use customized Allure reporting tool for jbehave ([link](https://github.com/tapack/allure-jbehave-reporter)). You could use Jbehave + Allure + Selenium Grid architecture.